# How to update a column in a table from a select query?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a query, but i want the results of the query to be updated to another table, in 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th column because i already have values in the first and second column.

my query:

```
INSERT INTO customer_info (reader_ID,tag_no,area,max_timestamp) 
SELECT   aisle_info.reader_ID,tag_no,
         aisle_info.area,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME
FROM     tag_logs
   INNER JOIN aisle_info ON
         tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID
WHERE    tag_no = 515988190124;
```

## 1364 - Field 'Customer_name' doesn't have a default value

Comment: As you said it should be an update statement and not insert into select..

Comment: not getting it right 
UPDATE customer_info reader_ID, tag_no, area, max_timestamp VALUES
(SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID,tag_no, aisle_info.area, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME
FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID
WHERE tag_no = 515988190124);
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES
(SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID,tag_no, aisle_info.area, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECO' at line 1

Comment: the pseudo code i have suggested is in TSQL..you can search `Mysql update with join syntax ` to resolve the error..

Comment: you are trying to insert but asking for update. please post with some clarity

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL - you should write an `update` statement instead of `insert into select` as you are updating (adding) values to an existing row in table `customer_info`. The pseudo code should look like:

```
Update C
set C.reader_ID     = A.reader_ID,
    C.tag_no        = A.tag_no,
    C.area          = A.area,
    C.max_timestamp = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(T.timestamp),MAX(T.timestamp))

from customer_info C
join aisle_info  A on A. tag_no = C. tag_no --Change here for correct join condition
join tag_logs T ON T.reader_ID = A.reader_ID
WHERE T.tag_no = 515988190124;
```